# Including data from multiple rows in CartoDB infowindow?

Tags: javascript, sql, carto, infowindow

I have a visualization in CartoDB of a set of data points in table `pointlayer`.  I am using cartodb.js and have a nice map for browser consumption.

When a user clicks on a point, I'd like to run a sql query that returns multiple rows relating to the clicked-upon point, and I'd like to put all that into the infowindow.

```
select column_a column_b, etc
from anothertable
  join pointlayer
  on pointlayer.point_id = anothertable.point_id
where
  pointlayer.point_id = <cartodb_id of clicked on point>
```

`anothertable` may have 0 or more rows for any `point_id`

Is this possible with infowindows?  Looks to me like the answer is probably no: they are designed for a single row.  I suspect that I need to find a solution other than using CartoDB's infowindow (e.g. using Leaflet's popup), but I thought I would ask.

[Getting info from multiple rows in single popup of CartoDB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91983) suggests to "actually query the table and get back all data."  It doesn't state that the infowindow itself can be used to display it...though I could be reading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with CartoDB.js. This link will help you:
http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/378c6dc0d43654280757

Comment: I might be missing something here, but it looks like this example is joining two tables with a one-to-one relationship and returning a single row comprised of a field or two from each table.  I have a one-to-many relationship and need to retrieve multiple rows (one for each of the "many" table); each row is comprised of a few fields from each table.  All rows will be displayed in the infowindow

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use PostgreSQL aggregate functions to solve this. Assuming your columns are strings, you could just use `string_agg(expression, delimiter)` on the query in order to retrieve several columns in just one row.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion - I'm relatively new to PostgreSQL and hadn't come across string_agg before, and I can see it's potential usefulness in similar situations.  However, it's important for me that my returned data actually is multiple rows - I'm using them for various purposes for which it's much simpler if they are separate rows.